Markdown hyperlink
I have these function which work well to convert general markdown to hyperlink:


const parseMarkdownToHTML = (markdownText) => {
    const markdownItems = markdownText.split(';').filter(item => item.trim() !== '');

    return markdownItems.map(item => {
        const regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/g;
        return item.replace(regex, (match, text, link) => {
            return `<a href='${link}'>${text}</a>`;
        }).trim();
    }).join('; ');
}

console.log(parseMarkdownToHTML(
    "[hyperlink text](https://example.com); [[text] hyperlink text](https://example.com)"
));



My issue is when there's something like [[text] hyperlink text](https://example.com) it fails to compile into <a href='https://example.com'>[text] hyperlink text</a>;
Any idea what should be improved for the function?

why the extra closing bracket ?

whoops my bad. it shouldn't be extra closing bracket

Try the links regex here

The issue is that [^\]]+ matches until the next closing parenthesis, which is the one after text]. Something like this would ensure that after an opening [ the regex looks until the boarder between text and link (](). Don't know if there exists a markdown parser in JS... that would be a preffereable option in terms of robustness...

Replace ([^\]]+) with (.+?) should work

bt. if you're plannig to parse markdown completely (as opposed to just extract some links), regexes are definitely not the way to go.

See https://regex101.com/r/XEnDHO/1

@WiktorStribiżew It's not about matching balanced brakets, unbalanced brackets could also be a valid markdown hyperlink label: [unclosed

Don't forget that images are exactly the same but with a ! in front of it. And it is also possible to have a title attribute, placed after the URL, in double or single quotes or even between parenthesis (ex: [Chapter 3](#chapter-3 "Jump to chapter 3")). So the regex should be a bit more sophisticated, especially split into several steps, the first one to match links or images and the second step to analyse the URL and the optional title attribute. This can be done in your replacement callback. Startup to help doing it: https://regex101.com/r/pc3idK/1

@HaoWu: according to the CommonMark spec, brackets have to be balanced, unbalanced brackets have to be escaped.

@WiktorStribiżew: First, I didn't close nor re-open this question. About closing the question as a duplicate: even if the question has the [regex] tag and the first idea that comes to his author is to use a simple regex replacement, the subject here is how to parse (and transform) a Markdown hyperlink that can be done in several ways, and not what is the regex to do it. IMO, I think the best way here is to tokenize the string. But this question may be more difficult than it seems if subject string contains other markdown features. The question may be how to parse Markdown.
